# How can I use strcat() within an if-else statement to change based on a user inputs "yes" or "no"?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, strcat, cmath

I am trying to make a basic choose-your-own-adventure style game by developing a basic system by which the program takes user char input and makes a decision using if-else statements to append strings in a certain pattern. In the following program I have tried to use strcat after a set of conditions to yield different output, but my outputs keep failing miserably. Any help someone could offer would be incredible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ios>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str1[50]= "F*ck";
    char str2[50]= "You";
    char str3[50]= "Me";

    char answer[50];

    cout<< "Do you like rock music yes or no?";
    cin>> answer;

    if (answer== "no"){
        cout<< strcat(str1,str2);
    } else (answer== "yes");{
        cout<< strcat(str1,str3);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `==` operator to compare C-style strings, you're actually comparing the addresses, not the contents, of the strings, which is not helpful in this case.  Try using the `strcmp()` library routine instead, and you'll probably get a lot farther with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare the contents of C-style strings using `operator==`. You need to use `strcmp()` instead:

```cpp
if (strcmp(answer, "no") == 0)
```

Also, `else (answer== "yes");{` is wrong too. Not only because of the comparison issue, but also because you are missing a required `if`, and have an erroneous `;`. It should be `else if (strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0){` instead.

That being said, you really should be using `std::string` instead of `char[]`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string str1 = "F*ck";
    const string str2 = "You";
    const string str3 = "Me";

    string answer;

    cout << "Do you like rock music yes or no?";
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == "no"){
        cout << str1 << str2;
    } else if (answer == "yes"){
        cout << str1 << str3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (answer== "no")` You're comparing the *memory address* of `answer` and the string literal `"no"`, so that condition is `false`

You should use `strcmp()` like this:

```cpp
if(strcmp(answer, "no") == 0)
```

Also, your `else` has the wrong syntax. You should use `else if`

Change that to:

```
else if (strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0)
{
    std::cout<< strcat(str1,str3);
}
```

Or even better, throw C-style string out of the window and use `std::string` instead.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <limits>
// using namespace std; is bad
int main()
{
    std::string str1{"F*ck"};
    std::string str2{"You"};
    std::string str3{"Me"};

    std::string answer;

    std::cout<< "Do you like rock music yes or no?";
    std::cin>> answer;

    if (answer == "no")
    {
        std::cout<< (str1 + str2);
    } 
    else if(answer == "yes")
    {
        std::cout << (str1 + str3);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rewrite the program and it now works. Gonna be real helpful for a text-based choose your own adventure game. The new program is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char str1[50]= "F*ck";
    char str2[50]= " You";
    char str3[50]= " Me";

    char answer[50];


    cout<< "Do you like rock music (yes or no)?"<<endl;

    cin>> answer;


    if (strcasecmp(answer,"no") == 0){
        cout<< strcat(str1,str2)<<endl;
    } else if (strcasecmp(answer,"yes") == 0){
        cout<< strcat(str1,str3)<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<< strcat(str1," off")<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```